# angular factory - real life scenario example?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

After reading a lot about the differences between factory and services, I think I finally got it, but most articles says that 70% of the times I would use factory and that doesn't make any sense. Why would I want a scenario that for each controller/directive there is a different object of the same factory.

For start, I built a simple contacts list web and a service (not factory) that contain all the contacts. For each directive/controller that want them, I will inject the service and all will have the same instance of the same service so any change from any controller/directive, all will still have the most updated contacts, because there is only one contacts array in my web.

Can you show me real-life scenario that needs the implementation of a factory instead of a service?

Comment: factory is a singleton .... so there is no `different object of the same factory`

Comment: but I can pass params to the factory function to get some logic before the factory returns. so what exactly "singleton" means? @charlietfl

Comment: yes you could but it depends what sort of params you are referring to

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaken on the difference between a "factory" and a service.

service() and factory() are two methods to register a new service in an angular module. Whatever the way you choose, that service will always be a singleton. The only difference is how Angular will create the service.

If you use

```
app.service('foo', function() { ... });
```

angular will expect that function you pass to be a constructor function. It will use `new` to invoke the constructor function, and that function will initialize the 'foo' service that way:

```
this.someMethod = ...;
this.somOtherMethod = ...;
```

`this`, in that case, is the `foo` service.

If you use

```
app.factory('foo', function() { ... });
```

angular will expect the function you pass to be a factory function. I.e. the role of this function is to **return** an object that is the `foo` service. That function will thus do something like

```
var service = {};
service.someMethod = ...;
service.someOtherMethod = ...;
return service;
```

In both cases, angular will only invoke the constructor or factory once and only once. That is what guarantees that the service is a singleton. And the created/returned object will constitute the singleton service.